# Kernel source in Yocto SDK missing macros definition

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, yocto

I am working on porting kernel module from kernel 2.x to 5.15. I have installed the yocto sdk on my building host, which contains the 5.15 kernel source tree. After changing the kernel source path of the linux driver makefile, I am seeing the below error. I am new to linux driver development, and hoping to get some guidance here. Thank you very much !

```
In file included from ./arch/arm64/include/asm/hwcap.h:9,
                 from ./arch/arm64/include/asm/arch_timer.h:12,
                 from ./arch/arm64/include/asm/timex.h:8,
                 from ./include/linux/timex.h:67,
                 from ./include/linux/time32.h:13,
                 from ./include/linux/time.h:60,
                 from ./include/linux/compat.h:10,
                 from /path/to/driver/driver_main.c:19:
./arch/arm64/include/asm/cpufeature.h: In function ‘system_supports_cnp’:
./arch/arm64/include/asm/cpufeature.h:762:37: error: ‘ARM64_HAS_CNP’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘ARM64_HAS_PAN’?
  762 |                 cpus_have_const_cap(ARM64_HAS_CNP);
      |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                     ARM64_HAS_PAN
./arch/arm64/include/asm/cpufeature.h:762:37: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
./arch/arm64/include/asm/cpufeature.h: In function ‘system_supports_address_auth’:
./arch/arm64/include/asm/cpufeature.h:768:37: error: ‘ARM64_HAS_ADDRESS_AUTH’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘ARM64_HAS_RAS_EXTN’?
  768 |                 cpus_have_const_cap(ARM64_HAS_ADDRESS_AUTH);
      |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                     ARM64_HAS_RAS_EXTN
./arch/arm64/include/asm/cpufeature.h: In function ‘system_supports_generic_auth’:
./arch/arm64/include/asm/cpufeature.h:774:37: error: ‘ARM64_HAS_GENERIC_AUTH’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  774 |                 cpus_have_const_cap(ARM64_HAS_GENERIC_AUTH);
      |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./arch/arm64/include/asm/cpufeature.h: In function ‘system_uses_irq_prio_masking’:
./arch/arm64/include/asm/cpufeature.h:785:36: error: ‘ARM64_HAS_IRQ_PRIO_MASKING’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  785 |                cpus_have_const_cap(ARM64_HAS_IRQ_PRIO_MASKING);
      |                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./arch/arm64/include/asm/cpufeature.h: In function ‘system_supports_mte’:
./arch/arm64/include/asm/cpufeature.h:791:37: error: ‘ARM64_MTE’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘ARM64_SVE’?
  791 |                 cpus_have_const_cap(ARM64_MTE);
      |                                     ^~~~~~~~~
      |                                     ARM64_SVE
./arch/arm64/include/asm/cpufeature.h: In function ‘system_supports_bti’:
./arch/arm64/include/asm/cpufeature.h:802:68: error: ‘ARM64_BTI’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘ARM64_SVE’?
  802 |         return IS_ENABLED(CONFIG_ARM64_BTI) && cpus_have_const_cap(ARM64_BTI);
      |                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~
      |                                                                    ARM64_SVE
./arch/arm64/include/asm/cpufeature.h: In function ‘system_supports_tlb_range’:
./arch/arm64/include/asm/cpufeature.h:808:37: error: ‘ARM64_HAS_TLB_RANGE’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘ARM64_HAS_PAN’?
  808 |                 cpus_have_const_cap(ARM64_HAS_TLB_RANGE);
      |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                     ARM64_HAS_PAN
```

Googling did not give me the right answer, and I was wondering whether the problem comes from the kernel source in the yocto sdk.